# LDAPS connection with ASP.Net/C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, active-directory, ldap

I have a connection string for LDAP protocol

> ldap://ldap.example.com:636/DC=users,DC=buyers

which works fine.

But I need to use a LDAPS connection :

> ldaps://ldap.example.com/DC=users,DC=buyers

which does show up in ldp.exe windows form when I test the connection.

Unfotunately it does not work in the Asp.Net application. I get "Unknown error (0x80005000)".

I am not sure whether LDAPS string is even possible with Asp.Net. I downloaded the source code into *LDAPConnection.cs* class and was unable to find any valuable information.

Comment: Can you post the code used to connect to LDAP (content of LDAPConnection.cs) ?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Ndk3aUju is my code and https://pastebin.com/M95JyzgV is from ASP.Net source code. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The method you found that works is indeed using LDAPS:

```
ldap://ldap.example.com:636/DC=users,DC=buyers
```

That's the only way to do it. I do that in one of my existing projects. It doesn't understand "LDAPS://".

If you don't believe me :) fire up Wireshark as you debug. When it connects, you'll see the SSL handshake to your domain controller.

Port 636 is *only* for LDAPS. Port 389 is the non-SSL port.

If you have more than one domain, you can use port 3269 for the global catalog via SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me to connect to AD using LDAPS

```
ldapConnection = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier("your.LDAPSserver.com", 636));

var networkCredential = new NetworkCredential("UsernameWithoutDomain", "yourPassword", "AD.yourDOMAIN.com");
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.ProtocolVersion = 3;
ldapConnection.SessionOptions.VerifyServerCertificate = new VerifyServerCertificateCallback(ServerCallback);
ldapConnection.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
ldapConnection.Bind(networkCredential);
        
SearchRequest Srchrequest = new SearchRequest("CN=Users,DC=AD,DC=YOURCOMPANY,DC=COM", "mail=useremail@company.com", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree);
SearchResponse SrchResponse = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(Srchrequest);
```

// ServerCallback

```
private static bool ServerCallback(LdapConnection connection, X509Certificate certificate)
{
    return true;
}
```

Surprisingly it is also working when I am not using **networkCredential** and just using **ldapConnection.Bind();** Seems it is using my local credentials as default on my local machine.